Aggregate Initialization when initialization values is fewer than the number of members
As per the document, which states that[emphasise mine]:

Missing initializers in an initializer list
If an aggregate is initialized but the number of initialization values
is fewer than the number of members, then all remaining members are
initialized with an empty initializer list. In most cases, this will
perform value-initialization on those members.

How to understand that in the right way? How remaining members are initialized with an empty initializer list?
The document says this will perform value-initialization on those members in most cases. When is not that case?
Maybe it's easier to understand with a simple example code:
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  int a;
  int b;
};

int main() {
  S s = { 0 }; 
  S s1{ 0 }; 
  //the output will be always zeros?
  std::cout<<"s.a = " <<s.a <<", s.b = " <<s.b<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"s1.a = "<<s1.a<<", s1.b = "<<s1.b<<std::endl; 
}


Recommended viewing: Timur Doumler: Initialisation in modern C++. It will blow your mind, and make you want to cry, all at once.

Obligatory The Nightmare of Initialization in C++ by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.

@Eljay So just ignore them is the best choice? :) Is there any simpified rules to easily master? Just like this.

Best choice is to be aware of all of them, and by convention (you or your team's) settle on a style.  There are no simplified rules that are easy to master, because that is antithetical to C++.


How remaining members are initialized with an empty initializer list?

The same way as A a = {}; (see [dcl.init.aggr] p5.2).
This member initialization is not equivalent to value-initialization when the member is of a class type that does not have a default constructor (which is called if it exists; see [dcl.init.list] p3.5), but has a constructor taking std::initializer_list (which is called otherwise; see [dcl.init.list] p3.7).
struct A {
    A(std::initializer_list<int>) {}  // #1
};

A a = {};  // calls #1

struct B {
    int x;
    A a;
};

B b = {42};  // b.a is initialized by calling #1


Thank you for the rapid reply. What's empty initializer list?  It's {}?

@John Yes { }

If I understand you correctly, demo.y is guaranteed to be {} (i.e. 0 for int{}) for struct Demo{int x, int y}; Demo demo = {42};? Am I right?

@John Right. Since int does not have an initializer-list constructor, value-initialization is performed.

@cpplearner It may disturb you. But I need to say that you save me hours. Thank you so much.
